Correct example illustration the sum identity in a lemma concerning monomial ideals for Grobner bases?
The following are partly taken from Malik and Sen's Fundamentals of Abstract Algebra
Background
Lemma 27.2.14:  Let $I$ be a momomial ideal and $f\in K[x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1},x_n]$.
Then the following are equivalent
$(i)$ $f\in I$.
$(ii)$ Every term of $f$ lies in $I$.
$(iii)$ $f=\sum_{\alpha=0}^{t} a_\alpha x^{\alpha}$ for some $a_\alpha \in K$ and $x^\alpha\in I, 0\leq \alpha \leq t$.

Proof: That $(iii)\Rightarrow (ii)\Rightarrow(i)$ is immediate.
$(i)\Rightarrow (iii)$    Since $f\in I, f=\sum_{i=1}^{q} h_{i} x^{\alpha(i)}$ for some $h_i\in K[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ and $\alpha(i)\in A$, where $I=\langle\{x^\alpha\mid\alpha \in A\}\rangle$.  Now $h_i=\sum_{j=0}^{n_i} k_{ij} x^{\beta(ij)}, i=1,\ldots,q, k_{ij}\in K,$ for all $i,j$. Thus,
$$f=\sum_{i=1}^{q}\sum_{j=q}^{m_i} k_{ij} x^{\beta(ij)}x^{\alpha(i)}$$
Therefore, $(iii)$ holds since $x^{\beta(ij)}x^{\alpha(i)}$ is a monomial in $I$.

Here is a screenshot of Lemma 27.2.14 (in the screenshot),

Questions
With regards the Lemma 27.2.14 above, would the following example:  $$f(x,y,z)=2x^2y-3xy^3z+4y^2z^5+5y^3x^2z^4=x(2xy-3y^3z)+y^2(4z^5+5x^2yz^4)$$ satisfy the sum identity:  $\sum_{i=1}^{q}\sum_{j=1}^{m_i} k_{ij} x^{\beta(ij)}x^{\alpha(i)}$ in that lemma?
Using $f(x,y,z)$ as an example with both $i,j=1,2$, for $f(x,y,z)=x(2xy-3y^3z)+y^2(4z^5+5x^2yz^4)$, we have
$h_1=2xy-3y^3z, h_2=4y^2z^5+5x^2y^3z^4$
$x^{\alpha(1)}=x,x^{\alpha(2)}=y^2$
$x^{\beta(11)}=xy,x^{\beta(12)}=y^3z, x^{\beta(21)}=z^5, x^{\beta(22)}=x^2yz^4$
$k_{11}=2, k_{12}=-3 ,k_{21}=4 ,k_{22}=5$
The reason I am asking about if my example is correct because any abstract algebra text that I have consulted that have grobner bases with the above lemma, there were no examples for illustration the sum identity and also because I am not sure why when decomposing $\sum_{i=1}^{q} h_{i} x^{\alpha(i)}$ , is it really necessary to have $x^{\beta(ij)}$ and $k_{ij}$.
Thank you in advance

Assuming that your monomial ideal is $I = \langle{x,y^2}\rangle$, then yes, $f$ satisfies the sum identity. Though, there's a small mistake where you want your $x^{\beta(ij)}$ to be monomials with coefficient $1$, meaning you want $$x^{\beta(11)}=xy,x^{\beta(12)}=y^3z, x^{\beta(21)}=z^5, x^{\beta(22)}=x^2yz^4$$ instead.
Regarding the necessity of $x^{\beta(ij)}$ and $k_{ij}$, statement (iii) of the lemma wants you to realize $f$ as a linear combination of monomials in $I$ with coefficients in $K$, and using the $x^{\beta(ij)}$ and $k_{ij}$ achieves this. The sum $\sum_{i=1}^{q} h_{i} x^{\alpha(i)}$ is a linear combination of monomials in $I$ with coefficients in $K[x_1,\ldots,x_{n}]$, which in the current form does not immediately satisfy the condition in statement (iii).

I edit my post according to your suggestions.  I let $x^{\beta(11)}=xy,x^{\beta(12)}=y^3z, x^{\beta(21)}=z^5, x^{\beta(22)}=x^2yz^4$, $k_{11}=2, k_{12}=-3 ,k_{21}=4 ,k_{22}=5$.  Is my editing correct?  I have three quick following up questions. First, at the end when you say $\sum_{i=1}^{q} h_{i} x^{\alpha(i)}$ doesn't satisfy (iii) of the lemma is because $h_i$ consists of elements with coefficients in $K$ and monomial terms from $K[x_1,\ldots,x_{n}]$.  Meaning each $h_i\in K[x_1,\ldots,x_{n}]$ so it can further be decomposed.  Second, the way I picked the generators...

...$\langle x, y^2\rangle$ for the terms of $f$ is not supposed to be unique.  Meaning, I could have chosen $x^{\alpha(1)}=x,x^{\alpha(2)}=z$ instead and that would work equally well.  Lastly, the element $x^\alpha$ of $I$, the $x$ is simply a placed holder variable where it can consist of more than one variable from a monomial, and $\alpha$ would be sum of the powers of a monomial which consists of sum of exponents of each monomial terms.  So we have for $\alpha$ in the Lemma, $\alpha={(\alpha(i), \beta(ij))\in A\mid i,j=1,2}$ and for our example,...

...$\alpha={(\alpha(i), \beta(ij))\mid i,j=1,2}={((1,0,0),(1,1,0)),((1,0,0),(0,3,1)),((0,2,0),(0,0,5)),((0,2,0),(2,1,4))}$, where $\alpha(1)=(1,0,0), \alpha(2)=(0,2,0),\beta(11)=(1,1,0),\beta(12)=(0,3,1),\beta(21)=(0,0,5), \beta(22)=(2,1,4).$  In the proof of the Lemma, there is really no good ways to distinguish between $\alpha, \alpha(i), \beta(ij).$

Yes, your editing is correct. Sorry, your questions aren't completely clear to me, since they seem more like comments rather than questions. I will try my best to address them. (1) Yes, $f = \sum_{i=1}^{q} h_{i} x^{\alpha(i)}$ satisfies (iii) because you can decompose each $h_i$ into $K$-linear combinations of monomials. You use the $k_{ij}$ and $x^{\beta(ij)}$ to show this. $x^{\beta(ij)} x^{\alpha(i)} = x^{\beta(ij) + \alpha(i)}$ is then a monomial in $I$ so you can then see $f$ is a $K$-linear combination of monomials in $I$.

(2) Using $x$ and $z$ for generators also makes $f$ satisfy (iii), but this is not the same monomial ideal as $\langle x, y^2 \rangle$. (3) Here, everything seems mostly correct except for $\alpha$. $\alpha$ is not a set, it is an index for the sum. It should be $\alpha = \alpha(i) + \beta(ij)$ for $i,j=1,2$ since $x^{\beta(ij)}x^{\alpha(i)} = x^{\beta(ij) + \alpha(i)}$. I'm not sure what you mean by "no good ways to distinguish between $\alpha, \alpha(i), \beta(ij)$."

What i mean by no good ways to distinguish between $\alpha, \alpha(i), \beta(ij)$ is at first i thought i need to apply some sort of transformation for the different index of summation between $\alpha$ and $\alpha(i), \beta(ij)$.   But after looking at the sum identity: $\sum_{\alpha=0}^{t} a_\alpha x^{\alpha}=\sum_{i=1}^{q}\sum_{j=q}^{m_i} k_{ij} x^{\beta(ij)}x^{\alpha(i)}$ again; $\alpha$ only takes on value from $\alpha(i)+\beta(ij)$.  So in the example of $f(x,y,z)$, the degree of its monomials...

are: $3,5,7\text{ and }9$? $\alpha$ takes only those four values? I don't have to worry about $\alpha=0,1,2,4,6,8$?

Yes, you can just say the coefficient $a_\alpha = 0$ for the values of $\alpha$ where $\alpha \neq \beta(ij) + \alpha(i)$.

thank you so much for answering all my questions.
